# Why does emacs lisp/elisp (contrary to Common Lisp) reject quoted symbol names as unknown variables?

Tags: list, variables, emacs

The following function call works in Common Lisp, but fails with Emacs Lisp that does not accept the quoted symbol passed as the first argument, with the Debugger reporting a Lisp error: “void-variable hammer.” I would appreciate any explanation of this difference between Common Lisp and ELisp.

```lisp
(defvar *glist* nil)

(defun add-to-global-list (item ctgry)
  (let ((elem (assoc ctgry *glist*))
    (newlst *glist*))
    (cond
     (elem
      (setf (cdr elem) (list (append (cadr elem) (list item)))))
     (t
      (setf newlst (append newlst (list (list ctgry (list item)))))))
    newlst))

(setf *glist* (add-to-global-list 'hammer 'tools))
```

Comment: Your code gives me `(setf *glist* (add-to-global-list 'hammer 'tools))` => `((tools (hammer)))` (and no error) in Emacs.

Comment: @phils: Thank you.  Very useful to know.  I will fiddle around with my Emacs init.el file and even try a fresh Emacs install.

Comment: I don't think you need to reinstall Emacs (not unless you're using an unusually-broken unstable release at present).  I would be surprised if this isn't a matter of accidentally not testing what you had believed you were testing.  Run `emacs -Q` and then try the code you've shown in that instance.